# Creating SQL UNION where second side of the union depends on first side

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would .like to perform  a union of two queries where second query depends on first:

```
SELECT * FROM company_res t1
UNION
SELECT * FROM company_res t2
WHERE t2.company_id IN (
  SELECT c.id
  FROM company c
  WHERE c.parent_id = t1.company_id
)
ORDER BY company_id, year_code
```

However, when I run this queries in psql I get an error to the effect that t1 in second query does have a `FROM`-clause.

Is it possible to have `UNION` of tow queries that depend on each other?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Conceptually the query you have posted doesn't seem to make any sense. Perhaps post some example data and desired results.

Answer (score 2):

From your partial example I think you're trying to make a [recursive query](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-with.html), and not a classical UNION query, that's an adavnced for of UNIONS if fact.

You need to perform some selections on company_res, and then to add parents of theses companies.

The basic form is:

```
WITH RECURSIVE t(n) AS (
    SELECT 1
  UNION ALL
    SELECT n+1 FROM t
)
SELECT n FROM t LIMIT 100;
```

In you case something like that maybe:

```
WITH RECURSIVE rectable(
 company_id,
 field2,
 field3,
 parent_id) AS (
    -- here the starting rows, t1 in your example
    SELECT 
      company_res.company_id,
      company_res.field2,
      company_res.field3,
      company.parent_id
    FROM company_res
    INNER JOIN company ON company_res.company_id=company.id
    WHERE (here any condition on the starting points)
  UNION ALL
    -- here the recursive part
    SELECT 
     orig.company_id,
     orig.field2,
     orig.field3,
     orig.parent_id
    FROM rectable rec,company_res orig
    INNER JOIN company ON orig.company_id=company.id
    WHERE company.parent_id=rec.company_id
    -- here you could add some AND sections if you want
)
SELECT company_id,field2, field3,parent_id
FROM rectable
ORDER BY parent_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `SELECT * FROM company_res t1` in your query is going to provide you with everything from `company_res`, regardless of what else you `UNION` it with from `company_res`. I doubt that's what you're looking for. See the answer from shahkalpesh.